# How can I insert a button in a form connected to a parametric query in ms access with auto-fill

Tags: ms-access-2016

My problem is that I have:

1. a **parametric query** that finds me the *games* played specifically by a *player* through an id;
2. a **form** through which I scroll through all the *players* in my database.

My goal is to insert a button in the form to auto-fill my query, using the data present at that moment on the form, and then return the results to me.

Anyone have any idea how to make it work?

-I am currently working on Access (Version 2112 Build 16.0.14729.20254).

Answer (score 0):

First add to the parameter query under the ID column view, criteria area, the a criteria that is similar to the one below

[Forms]![book]![bookid]

Where book is name of the form, you want to place the command button on
and bookid is name of the control on the form that has the ID field

Next you save the parameter query/select query

Finally you create a command button that will run the query.

Once you click the command button, it will display records in a query where the ID is the current records ID.

I have attached some images that explain the steps.

[image: Query output sample]

[image: Query design view]

[image: Command Button step 1]

[image: Command button step 2]

[image: Command button step 3]

[image: Command button step 4]

[image: Form view]